# Frameless Glass shower door handle

Tags: doors, shower, glass

[image]Is there an industrial standard relating to the distance between the shower door handle and the edge of the glass door?

I cut my fingertip completely off by swinging the door outward.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn! That hurts just thinking about it!

Comment: If you make a habit of using your right hand for the door, your fingers will be facing the other way and will stay safe.

Comment: This is my left hand inside the shower, showing how it happened I used my right hand to get in.

Answer (score 1):

This type of door is problematic for just the reason that you show. It would obviously be better if the handle were positioned a bit farther from the door edge. But somehow I doubt that there is any type of international standard for the spacing requirement. Clearly there would be a trade off for the width of the door and how far the handle is positioned from the hinge side of the door. With the narrower door and the handle more toward the center of the door it would be harder to open and close.

One thing to consider is that some doors like this have a silicon strip that is attached to one side and has a flap to overlap the other side of the door gap. These are designed to keep shower spray from getting out through the door crack. They also keep the door from opening both directions. The combination of the single direction door opening and the padding afforded by the silicon strip maybe you can minimize the chances of losing another finger tip.

Comment: Thank you! Our builder said that "  the handle is up to industrial standerds" which I doubt.